# Abstract Factory Pattern Client Code

Tags: c++, design-patterns, factory, abstract

I am trying to write my client code for abs factory but I am stuck at the client code. I can't instantiate any Bshell by `Factorymaker.getFactory("Bshell");` The code is compiling without the client code

(I am new to stackoverflow. My iostream is normal in my code.)

```
#include <iostream> 

using namespace std;
//This is the abstract product.
class Shell {

public:
    virtual void printShell(){ cout << "I am the abstract product\n"; }
};
class Bshell : public Shell {

public:
    Bshell();
    Bshell(string arg){ cout << "I am " << arg << endl; }
    void printShell(){ cout << "I am Bshell\n"; }
};
class Cshell : public Shell {

public:
    Cshell();
    Cshell(string arg){ cout << "I am " << arg << endl; }
    void printShell(){ cout << "I am Cshell\n"; }
};
class Kshell : public Shell {

public:
    Kshell();
    Kshell(string arg){ cout << "I am " << arg << endl; }
    void printShell(){ cout << "I am Kshell\n"; }
};
//This is the abstract factory.
class ShellFactory {

public:
    virtual Shell* createBshell();
    virtual Shell* createCshell();
    virtual Shell* createKshell();
};
//Concrete factories
class BShellFactory : public ShellFactory {

public:
    Shell* createBshell(){ return new Bshell("Bshell"); }
};
class CShellFactory : public ShellFactory {

public:
    Shell* createCshell(){ return new Cshell("Cshell"); }
};
class KShellFactory : public ShellFactory {

public:
    Shell* createKshell(){ return new Kshell("Kshell"); }
};
//indirectly instantiating factories
class Factorymaker {

private:
    ShellFactory *sf = NULL;
public:
    ShellFactory* getFactory(string choice){

        if (choice == "Bshell"){ sf = new BShellFactory(); }
        else if (choice == "Cshell"){ sf = new CShellFactory(); }
        else if (choice == "Kshell"){ sf = new KShellFactory(); }
        return this->sf;
    }
};
int main()
{
    Factorymaker *fmaker = new Factorymaker();
    ShellFactory *sf = fmaker.getFactory("Bshell");
    Bshell bshellproduct = sf.createBshell();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fmaker` and `sf` are pointers, so use `->` not `.` to access their members.

The return type of `sf->createBshell()` is `Shell*`, so that should be the type of `bshellproduct`.

Your compiler should have told you all of that.

Comment: Thanks! My compiler says, 
undefined reference to `vtable for ShellFactory'
undefined reference to `ShellFactory::createBshell()'
undefined reference to `typeinfo for ShellFactory'
<br>
Factorymaker *fmaker = new Factorymaker();
    ShellFactory *sf = fmaker->getFactory("Bshell");
    Shell* bshellproduct = sf->createBshell();

Comment: @SinanTalebi: That's because you declare three pure functions in the `ShellFactory` base class, and only override one in each concrete factory. You should probably change the interface to a single `create()` function.